# Effect on probability of adding a constant to the random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this question in my notebook.A Drunk person performs a random walk over positions $0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots$ He starts at 0, he takes successive 1 unit steps going to the right with probability p and to the left with probability $1 - p$, his steps are independent let $X$ denote his position after $n$ steps. Find the $E(X)$.So $$X_i=\begin{cases} 1, & \text{if he takes the step to the right}\\ -1, & \text{if he takes the step to the left}\end{cases}$$ then $X=X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$, gives the position of the drunkard after $n$ steps.

> then this part that I don't understand

The solution defines $Y_i=\frac{1}{2}\left(X_{i}+1\right)$. Then $$Y_i=\begin{cases} \frac{1+1}{2} =1, & \text{with probability } p \\[3pt]
 \frac{-1+1}{2}=0, & \text{with probability }1-p\end{cases}$$
Now I am wondering why does the probability of random variable  $Y_i$ is equal to the probability of random variable $X_i$, Does adding constant or say changing scales does not affect probability, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $Y_i=\frac{1}{2}(X_i+1)$ means that $Y_i$ can take on the values $0$ or $1$ since $X_i$ is either $1$ or $-1$. $Y_i$ is $0$ when $X_i$ is $-1$ which happens with probability $1-p$. $Y_i$ is $1$ when $X_i$ is $1$ which happens with probability $p$. Thus, $Y_i$ is $1$ with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$. If you want to know more about functions of random variables, which this is an example of, check out the cdf technique. You don't need it here because this is a simple discrete linear problem but for more complicated transformation it is useful.

Comment: Ohh, I understand as Y also gets its value due to X hence their probabilities are equal, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way $Y_i$ is defined, its value is completely determined by the value of $X_i$. When $X_i = -1$, $Y_i=\frac{1}{2}(-1+1) = 0$. Similarly, when $X_i = 1$, there is no alternative but for $Y_i = 1$.

The probability that $X_i = 1$ is $p$. Therefore, the probability that $Y_i = 1$ must also be $p$.